# Proofs about functions that depend on the ordering of their alternatives

Tags: pattern-matching, dependent-type, idris, theorem-proving

Having quite some experience in Haskell, I just recently started to use Idris for theorem proving. This is a minimal example that illustrates a problem I encountered when trying to prove rather simple statements.

Consider we have a total function `test`:

```
total test : Integer -> Integer
test 1 = 1
test n = n
```

Of course we see that the function could be simplified to `test n = n`, but let's prove it. I am simply going over all the cases:

```
total lemma_test : (n : Integer) -> test n = n
lemma_test 1 = Refl
lemma_test n = Refl
```

But, this doesn't type-check:

```
Type mismatch between
        n = n (Type of Refl) and
        test n = n (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                n
        and
                test n
```

So, the problem seems to be that Idris cannot infer for the second case of `lemma_test` that `n` is not equal to `1` and that also the second case of `test` must be applied.

We can, of course, try to explicitly list ALL the cases, which can be cumbersome, or impossible, as in the case for `Integer`s:

```
total lemma_test : (n : Integer) -> test n = n
lemma_test 1 = Refl
lemma_test 2 = Refl
lemma_test 3 = Refl
...
```

Is there a way to prove statements like this for functions that are not defined over a finite set of data constructors but instead depend on the fact that pattern-matching works from top to bottom, like `test` in this example?

Maybe there is a rather simple solution that I just fail to see, considering that functions like this occur quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, `Integer` is primitive, and not an inductively defined `Idris` type, therefore we can't do exhaustive pattern matching on it. More specifically, the issue is that in Idris (and actually in state-of-the-art Agda too!) we can't really prove things about "default" pattern matches, because they don't carry information about all the previous patterns that failed to match. In our case, `test n = 1` doesn't give us evidence that `n` is not equal to `1`.

The usual solution is to use decidable equality (`Boolean` equality could be good too) instead of fall-through:

```
import Prelude

%default total

test : Integer -> Integer
test n with (decEq n 1)
  test n | Yes p = 1
  test n | No  p = n

lemma_test : (n : Integer) -> (test n) = n
lemma_test n with (decEq n 1)
 lemma_test _ | (Yes Refl)  = Refl
 lemma_test n | (No contra) = Refl
```

Here, the `No` result carries explicit evidence about the failed match.

Comment: The information that it is not possible or at least difficult to prove something about "default" pattern matches is very helpful to me, thank you. I think/hope I can adapt my specific problems to use decidable equality, as you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `Integer` is defined, or how to do induction on it, etc., so this is not a full answer to your question; but maybe the `Nat` version is also going to be informative for you? (also, maybe you actually meant `Nat`, since in your second example you only enumerate the positive naturals?)

If you change `test` to use `Nat`s:

```
total test : Nat -> Nat
test (S Z) = 1
test n = n
```

then you can do exhaustive pattern matching in `lemma_test`:

```
total lemma_test : (n : Nat) -> test n = n
lemma_test (S Z) = Refl
lemma_test Z = Refl
lemma_test (S (S k)) = Refl
```

Comment: Do you regard my `Nat` example as relevant? You couldn't exhaustively list all patterns for `Nat` :)

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I simply used `Integer`s as an example for something that I can't really do exhaustive pattern matching with. Of course I could prove the statement with `Nat`s, but I am not interested in this particular (trivial) statement at all. Consider proving a statement for a data type with many constructors, and a function that matches a very particular pattern, and does something else when this particular pattern does NOT match. In the proof I also would have to do exhaustive pattern matching over all patterns that do NOT match, which are too many.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` isn't defined in Idris, but rather defers to GMP bigints. It's effectively opaque to Idris, and apparently not something you can reason about cases of at compile time in this way. With something like `Nat`, which is defined inductively, you can talk about proofs in the form of a base case and a recursive case.

That type error about `n` not being `test n` is telling you that Idris can't reduce the expression `test n`. I'm not sure that's how it's supposed to behave - obviously it's a total function, and it's supposed to reduce total functions afaik. Maybe that's related to the opacity of `Integer` to Idris?

You can test out the reduction at the repl, by introducing the free variable as a labmda param. E.g. `\n => test n` just echoes back `\n => test n : Integer -> Integer` (with nothing changed), however, if you remove the `test 1 = 1` case from your definition and try again, it echoes back `\n => n : Integer -> Integer` - it's reduced `test n` to `n`. And then your proof would work as-is.